# Big O notation example confusion

Tags: big-o

The problem in this case is asking if 2<sup>2n</sup> = O(2<sup>n</sup>)?

Now usually I solve for both inequalities in 0 <= 2<sup>2n</sup> <= c*2<sup>n</sup>.

0 <= 2<sup>2n</sup> is trivially true, and then I rewrite the other inequality as:

2<sup>n</sup>*2<sup>n</sup> <= c*2<sup>n</sup>, and the 2<sup>n</sup> cancel out, leaving us with 2<sup>n</sup> <= c. In every other example I have, we have to let c be a value that we assign to it, and then solve for values of n that make it true. However, in this case, we just get 2<sup>n</sup> <= c, and I don't really know how to interpret that. My professor said that this means that it is not O(2<sup>n</sup>)  "because there is no constant c that will ensure this for any value n", but for some reason I am really not understanding that conceptually. Can somebody explain this to me a little better or maybe re-word it differently?

Comment: Let 2^n = m. Is m^2 = O(m)? Sure, it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basis of the big-O notation is to determine how the size of the input (e.g., number of elements in an array) will effect the number of operations you need to perform.

In these cases, `C` represents a constant, however large it may be, that satisfies the inequality when `n -> ∞`. Here, when `n -> ∞`, obviously `2^n -> ∞`. Therefore, in order to uphold the inequality, you'd require `c -> ∞`. 
In other words, since no constant `C` upholds the inequality, `2^2n != O(2n)`.